# Google Button "cannot be cast to android.widget.Button"

Tags: android, widget, google-play-services

I'm trying to follow Google's instructions to import Google  Play Game Services at: 
https://developers.google.com/games/services/training/signin

```
<!-- sign-in button -->
<com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton
 android:id="@+id/sign_in_button"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

When I import the official Google Play Button (as shown above in the XML Layout), i get this error in my log:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{flash4life.gespant2015.com.flashreflex20/flash4life.gespant2015.com.flashreflex20.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton cannot be cast to android.widget.Button
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3255)
```

This is the entire Error Log:

```
08-15 19:57:25.961 472-472/flash4life.gespant2015.com.flashreflex20 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                  Process: flash4life.gespant2015.com.flashreflex20, PID: 472
                                                                                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{flash4life.gespant2015.com.flashreflex20/flash4life.gespant2015.com.flashreflex20.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton cannot be cast to android.widget.Button
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3255)
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3351)
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:222)
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1796)
                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7230)
                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
                                                                                   Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton cannot be cast to android.widget.Button
                                                                                      at flash4life.gespant2015.com.flashreflex20.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:107)
                                                                                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6877)
                                                                                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1136)
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3208)
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3351) 
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:222) 
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1796) 
                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158) 
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7230) 
                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

I assigned the Button in my Java:

```
signInButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sign-in-button);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**SignInButton** cannot be assigned to Button.

You can use it in this way:

```
SignInButton signInButton = (SignInButton) findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button);
```

If required, you can refer:
https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/sign-in

Comment: Thanks, it's worked for me, and save a lot of time.

Answer (score 1):

While it has the word button in it, as per the [SignInButton documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/SignInButton), `SignInButton` actually extends `FrameLayout`.

Every `View` supports setting an `OnClickListener` so there's no reason to cast it to `Button` at all.

Answer (score 0):

this is the SignInButton documentation,it is a frameLayout no a button 
public final class SignInButton extends FrameLayout implements View.OnClickListener

but it has the function you can use it 
void setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener listener)

so you can do it like that
signInButton = (SignInButton ) findViewById(R.id.sign-in-button);
signInButton.setOnClickListener(new OnCLickListener)

Answer (score 0):

**SignInButton** Can't assign to Button

You can use This way :(Kotlin)

```
        var signin = findViewById<View>(R.id.sign_in_button) as SignInButton
```